# Is the Banach Tarski Theorem applicable to a $4D$ sphere?

Tags: set-theory

Is the Banach Tarski Theorem applicable to a $4D$ sphere?

More generally is the theorem applicable to any dimension?

Comment: It is not applicable in dimensions less than $3.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/a-computational-perspective-on-set-theory/):

> Note that [the Banach-Tarski] paradox is available only in three and higher dimensions, but not in one or two dimensions.